# Send request to Google input tools in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-input-tools

I want to send some (about 200k) request to `Google Input API` and display results. For example I want to send `deep` and it must return:

```
["deep","dépenses","dépend","dépendance","dépendant"]
```

I tried following script but it's not helpful:

```
def request(word):
    url = 'https://inputtools.google.com/request?text=' + word + '&itc=fr-t-i0-und&num=5&cp=0&cs=1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=test'
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    print(res.status, res.reason)
```

I want to know how can achieve that? (see an example of what I want to achieve [here](https://inputtools.google.com/request?text=deep&itc=fr-t-i0-und&num=5&cp=0&cs=1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=test))

Comment: In what way is it not helpful?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I can get any result and it throws exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got your call syntax, but if you [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html), you'll see that you need to write you code as

```
import http.client
def request(word):
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('inputtools.google.com')
    conn.request('GET', '/request?text=' + word + '&itc=fr-t-i0-und&num=5&cp=0&cs=1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=test')
    res = conn.getresponse()
    print(res.status, res.reason)
    print(res.read())

request(word='deep')
```